# Don't understand 3rd argument to Backbone events binding

Tags: backbone.js

I'm reading up on how to use Backbone.js but it seems all the articles available online are all out of date compared to the latest version of the Backbone library? Which doesn't help!

I've seen for example an article by nettuts (first up in Google results) go into a discussion about using `Backbone.Controller` but that has been removed from Backbone so that was confusing to discover.

But regardless, my question is regarding the events object in Backbone.

With a 'View' you can do...

```
var ContactsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('View initialized');
    },

    events: {
        'change select': 'displaySelected'
    },

    displaySelected: function (event) {
        console.log('get model data and display selected user', event);
    }
});
```

...but you can't use the `events` property with a `Collection`, instead you need to use jQuery's bind method from within the `initialize` method...

```
var Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Contact,

    initialize: function(){
        this.bind('add', this.model_added, this);
    },

    model_added: function(){
        console.log('A new model has been created');
    }
});
```

...first of all, why is this?

But more importantly what is the 3rd argument `this` for? I looked up `bind` on the jQuery documentation (as there was no mention of `bind` on the Backbone site) and it doesn't have a 3rd argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `Backbone.Controller` was not removed, it was renamed to `Backbone.Router`, beside the manual you can check the [Change Log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog)

2) `.bind` was renamed to `.on` and you can check the 3rd argument (which is `context`) in the [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on), in `Backbone` you have `_.bindAll` from `Underscore` [documented here](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll) which assigns `this` to all functions that you specify.

3) `events` inside a `View` is something that listens to DOM events (click, mouseover, mousedown, etc) and of course you will know which DOM element was triggered, the `.bind` or let's say `.on` does something when an `.trigger` is called, the entire Backbone code is full of custom triggers so that you can, if you wish, to be notified of model.add, model.remove, collection.reset, etc. Check also [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents)

Answer (score 2):

The third argument is optional - it provides a way to pass a context to the handler function.

In JavaScript, `this` is contextual - it can and will change depending on what object you are inside of. By passing `this` to the optional `context` argument, you are passing along the scope of the object to which you bound the event. Doing so allows you to have that same context to work with in your handler.